# How to delete all (resizes of an) images inside folders except the main one

Tags: centos, scripting

We have a folder structure of:

```
assets/user/YYYY/MM/DD/ID/image.jpg|png|...
```

and there are over 8,000+ users posted on on different times and different IDs.

Within that same folder we create 6 different sizes of thumbnails such as:

```
assets/user/YYYY/MM/DD/ID/tn_image.jpg|png|...
assets/user/YYYY/MM/DD/ID/250x250_image.jpg|png|...
assets/user/YYYY/MM/DD/ID/600x600_image.jpg|png|...
...
```

How can I delete all of these resized versions and on?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the original images are the oldest images. You could go for a script that deletes every file that is newer than... So if your original image is more than 31 days old, use:

```
find assets/user/\*/\*/\*/\*/ -mtime -31 -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

BE CAREFUL! This line will search in all folders, so all the original images have to be the exact same aged. If they are not, then use specific folders for each. Like:

```
find assets/user/YYYY/MM/DD/ -mtime -31 -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: This answer isn't useful at all, because the images are "posted on different times and different IDs". The _pattern of filenames_ is most likely the key here, not the _last modified time_. You'll need the magic of _regular expressions_.